# How to get total number of requirements for a release from QC using macro

Tags: vba

I want to retrieve the total number of requirements for a release.PFB the example:

Say

```
Release 1:
 Code Drop 1
   Req 1
   Req 2
   Req 3
   Req 4
   Req 5
 Code Drop 2
   Req 1
   Req 2
   Req 3
   Req 4
```

I want to retrieve the total number of requirements in the below format:

```
Release 1      No of Req
Code Drop 1    5
Code Drop 2    4
Total          9
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is one long string, you could use regular expressions for this.  First get a set of Code Drop sections using pattern:

```
Code Drop.+(?=Code Drop)
```

Then for each one of those sections find the Code Drop itself with:

```
Code Drop \d+
```

and the number of "Req" matches with another pattern:

```
Req \d+
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://bytecomb.com/regular-expressions-in-vba/) on using regular expressions in VBA.